# Sequelize only consider one association at a time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using the orm sequelizeJs to model the database schema on my nodeJs project. The DB is mysql. 
I have 03 models that are defined as follows :

```
        // Worker model
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const Worker = sequelize.define("Worker", {
    workerId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    }
}
//Will put workerId into Order
Worker.associate = function (models) {
        models.Worker.hasMany(models.Order, { foreignKey: "workerId", constraints: false });
    };
//Will put workerId into Sale
Worker.associate = function (models) {
    models.Worker.hasMany(models.Sale, { foreignKey: "workerId", constraints: false });
};

return Worker;
}
    // Order model    
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Order = sequelize.define("Order", {
        orderId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
}
// Will put workerId into Order
Order.associate = function (models) {
        models.Order.belongsTo(models.Worker, {
            foreignKey: "workerId",
            targetKey: "workerId",
            constraints: false
        });
    };
return Order;
}

// Sale model    
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Sale = sequelize.define("Sale", {
    saleId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    }
//Will put orderId into Sale
Sale.associate = function (models) {
        models.Sale.belongsTo(models.Order, { foreignKey: "orderId", constraints: false });
    };
// Will put workerId into Sale
Sale.associate = function (models) {
        models.Sale.belongsTo(models.Worker, { foreignKey: "workerId", constraints: false });
    };
return Sale;
}
```

The association `1-to-Many` between `Order` and `Worker` works (`workerId` is imported into `Order`).

However I cannot get the association `1-to-1` between  `Sale` and `Worker` and the one between `Order` and `Sale` to work simultaneously. It is either one at the time that works. Meaning I can ONLY get `orderId` or `workerId` to be in the `Sale` model but not both , which I need to achieve.

I need to have both `1-to-1` relations between `Sale & Order`, and between `Sale & Worker`.

Can you spot anything I might have missed or misused ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I was creating the associations within two separate functions having the same name `associate`. I fixed it by moving the associations into the same function, like this:

```
Sale.associate = function (models) {
        models.Sale.belongsTo(models.Order, { foreignKey: "orderId", constraints: false });

       // Will put workerId into Sale
        models.Sale.belongsTo(models.Worker, { foreignKey: "workerId", constraints: false });
    };
```